# mysql innodb cluster : possible to upgrade myisam to innodb on live cluster?

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, innodb

Hello just wondering because all our databases are innodb but mysql db is not.. so when I create a user is not replicating.. so instead of having to create the user on each node, wonder how hard will it be to upgrade the mysql.user table to innodb. thanks

Comment: Don't touch system tables. MySQL owns these.

Comment: hello tadman ok so is safe to create users on all nodes manually?

Comment: "Safe" is a subjective thing. I'd ask on the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com), or search there for an answer to this question if one already exists.

Comment: oh didnt know  there was a dba site.. sorry.  I will. I did search only found one for Galera but not innodb http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/userchanges.html and they have a diff solution

Comment: No worries. That site is geared towards this sort of thing and can better answer it. Stack Overflow is for code-related questions and this pertains to replication, database internals.

Comment: I also voted to move to dba.stackexchange.com, but SPOILER: you cannot change the storage engine for system tables until MySQL 8.

Comment: @cfernandezlinux - The last part of that link points out that `CREATE USER` and `GRANT` _will_ be replicated.